# How to handle multi region and multi account aws infrastructure using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

My infrastructure is spread acrross multiple accounts and multiple region. I want to implement IaC for that using terraform. I have created modules for various core resources like VPC,ECS clusters etc. how to handle multiple region and accounts ??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start checking the [provider alias](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) option.  Basically you define a provider alias for each region or account.  Then when you create a resource or "call" a module you specify the provider alias to use.